# How to fix problem cache in nextjs using axios

Tags: caching, next.js

I'm trying to use nextjs server-side to GET my category data and set it in an input, so that the user can see the current category data and be able to edit and enter a new value. however, when the user edits a category, he is redirected through push to the page that shows all categories, and when he clicks on the menu, he uses push that redirects to the edit route, on the server side in the edit route Fetch the category and do what I said previously, but the first time it works. in the second one it works after 30 seconds, I'm sure this could be cache. I saw that in the documentation they use fetch by default which has features that disable the cache, however I tested it previously and was unsuccessful, but I would like to continue using axios as it has an interceptor functionality that makes it easier.

Código:

```
import { Api } from "@/utils";
import { EditCategoryLayout } from "./@root";
import { notFound } from "next/navigation";

type PageProps = {
    params: {
        categoryId: string
    },
    searchParams: {}
}

const getData = async (categoryId: string) => {
    return await Api.get('/store/category', {
        params: {
            categoryId
        }
    });
}

export default async function DashboardEditCategory(props: PageProps) {
    const { categoryId } = props.params;

    const req = await getData(categoryId);

    if (req.status !== 200 || req.data.error) notFound();

    return (
        <EditCategoryLayout id={categoryId} {...req.data as any} />
    )
}
```

Problem from cache nextjs

Answer (score 0):

By default, NextJs always cache GET method. If you want opt-out caching, your API route need to use one of below:

1. Using the Request object with the GET method. Read more [Opting out of caching](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers#opting-out-of-caching)
2. Opt-out caching entire route, by using [Route Segment Config](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config)

Comment: I tried using the methods above and it still didn't solve the problem. Whenever I use router.push it doesn't fetch again when a page has already loaded.